# Site out of a Wordpress network accesible with the same domain as the network

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have the following configuration in my server:

in /var/www/ I have three folders:

- WPnetwork
- phpBB
- WPsingle

I have 2 domains, one pointing to WPnetwork and other pointing to WPsingle. All of them work. Let's call them network.com and single.com

In my wpnetwork, I have 3 sites with subdomains which work:

- A.network.com
- B.network.com
- C.network.com

I want my phpBB site into the network.com domain, I don't really mind if it's forum.network.com or network.com/forum
I'm fighting with my wpnetwork's .htaccess to make phpbb accesible to the public, but I can't. Could you help me with this configuration?

My current htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
# RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Thank you everybody.

Comment: I don't think you can set up a domain with just `.htaccess`. You'll need to configure Apache to serve that up instead.

Comment: My domain is fully working, @Machavity, I just need to redirect the link to a folder of my server

Comment: If you want the phpbb in network.com/forum, then you need to put it there and then create an exception in .htaccess. If you want to keep the location as /var/www/phpbb then you will probably need to do an `Alias` which can not be done in .htaccess.